# .Net Core 3.1 RSA - unable to import Pkcs8PrivateKey

Tags: .net-core, cryptography, amazon-ecs, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an application that relies on a private key originally received in a .pem file.The application runs as a docker container in AWS ECS (Fargate). The private key contents have been moved to AWS Parameter Store to avoid dealing with multiple .pem files.

The code below imports this key and runs on my local machine. But the `CryptographicException` is always thrown in ECS with message 'ASN1 corrupted data.'.

```
                string pkcs8KeyString = exchange.Pem;
                pkcs8KeyString = pkcs8KeyString.Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty);
                pkcs8KeyString = pkcs8KeyString.Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty);
                RSA rsa = RSA.Create();

                try
                {
                    rsa.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(ReadOnlySpan<char>.Empty, Convert.FromBase64String(pkcs8KeyString), out _);
                }
                catch (CryptographicException e)
                {
                    //Log to ECS
                    Console.WriteLine("The key could not be imported!");
                    Console.WriteLine($"{e.GetType().FullName} {e.Message}");
                    throw;
                }
```

What is the difference between my local environment and ECS in this regard? What can I do to avoid the exception in ECS?

Comment: How are you loading the exchange.Pem from Parameter Store?. Can you please share your task definition details and any entryscript for container?.

Comment: @Imran `exchange` is an instance of `Exchange`, which is what the param store data binds to. It is injected into the class via `IConfiguration`, and the relevant value is deserialized into an `Exchange` object. I will also share the ECR deployment shell script.

Comment: aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1 | /bin/bash
docker build -t project-staging .
docker tag project-staging:latest 640848491082.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/project-staging:latest
docker push 640848491082.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/project-staging:latest

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with `ECDsa`, right now I figured it works on Windows (with CNG implementation) but it doesn't on Linux (with OpenSSL implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my research with `ECDsa` the method `ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey` really does require an encrypted key (PEM with `ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY` block) on Linux (or rather when using OpenSSL backed implementation) and throws if unencrypted key is given. On Windows (CNG backed implementation) both forms encrypted or unencrypred (PEM with just `PRIVATE KEY` block) are supported.

If unencrypred key is used, just use `ImportPkcs8PrivateKey`.

Edit: Just tested with `RSA` and it behaves exactly the same way as `ECDsa`.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I'll try to obtain an encrypted private key and loop back to accept your answer.

Comment: This should help `openssl pkcs8 -in priv.pem  -topk8 -v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES -out priv-crypt.pem`

Comment: Or using a stronger cipher `openssl pkcs8 -in priv.pem -topk8 -v2 aes-256-cbc -v2prf hmacWithSHA256 -out enckey.pem`

Comment: Or just use `ImportPkcs8PrivateKey`.

Comment: Maybe this is a useful link: [https://vcsjones.dev/key-formats-dotnet-3/](https://vcsjones.dev/key-formats-dotnet-3/).